# Some basic conceptual question in multivariable partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} =\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h}  = 0$

Similar to partial derivative with respect to $y$

Using the theorem that

> Suppose that the partial derivatives $D_jf_i(x)$ of the component
>   functions of $f$ exist at each point $x$ of A and are continuous on A .
>   Then $f$ is differentiable at each point of A.

We concludes that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

However, the question also asks me to show that $f$ is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of $0$.

isn't this kind of contradiction? So I think I've messed up the definitions.

Comment: You have not shown the partial derivatives are continuous (indeed, they are not).

Comment: @Chappers why is the partial derivatives aren't continuous ? (I thought the partial derivatives is simply 0)

Comment: You have to also consider both $x$ and $y$ not zero: it's not enough to check they are continuous on lines of constant $x$ or $y$.

Comment: @Chappers So the idea here is that we compute the partial derivative for x and y, and partial derivatives exists and but not continuous at $0$. Hence, $f$ is not class $C^1$? But how do I show that $f$ is differentiable? The existence of partial derivatives not enough to show that $f$ is differentiable, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Differentiable* here means that there is a linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ so that
$$ \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{ \lVert f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,k) - A (h,k) \rVert }{\lVert (h,k) \rVert} = 0. $$
You can in this case construct the map directly (hint: it's zero), and then it is easy to prove that this condition works at zero.

On the other hand, $C^1$ normally means that the first partial derivatives should be continuous. You can compute these explicitly in the usual way at a general point to show that this is not the case (you'll find discontinuities on the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$, I expect).

Reminder: as any first course in multivariable analysis should tell you, you have the proper inclusions

> $\{$Continuous partial derivatives at $x \} \subset \{ $Differentiable at $x \} \subset \{ $Partial derivatives exist at $x \} $,

so you can only prove in one direction from these sets.

Comment: @Chappers If $\gamma : I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, wouldn't existence of partial derivatives imply differentiability?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Those strict inclusions are for multivariate functions, not single-variable. In the case of one independent variable and multiple dependent variables, there is only one direction to take as $x \to a$ in the domain $I$, the derivative is a vector, and there is no notion of a *partial* derivative, precisely because there is only one variable.